# Connectivity issues to EKS Fargate pod

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, karpenter

I'm running an EKS cluster with several regular EC2 nodes, and a single pod running in fargate (karpenter). My problem is that I can't seem to connect from any of the EC2 nodes into the fargate pod. Here's what I've tried:

- Started ubuntu pod in one of the EC2 nodes, ran nslookup against the service in fargate, it resolves properly:

```
root@debug:/# nslookup karpenter.karpenter.svc.cluster.local
Server:     172.20.0.10
Address:    172.20.0.10#53

Name:   karpenter.karpenter.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.20.73.25
```

- Send curl request to fargate service:

```
root@debug:/# curl -I http://karpenter.karpenter.svc.cluster.local:8080/metrics
curl: (28) Failed to connect to karpenter.karpenter.svc.cluster.local port 8080 after 129842 ms: Connection timed out
```

- I've setup port forwarding directly to the karpenter service, and I'm able to connect just fine

So it seems the problem is just network connectivity from EC2 to Fargate. Any ideas on how else to troubleshoot this?

Comment: ever figure this one out?

Comment: It was an issue with security groups. I was adding the security group rules to the wrong group.

Comment: strange i thought fargate had no SGs.. i'll dig deeper into it.. thanks

Comment: More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html#fargate-gs-check-compatibility)